# Perl, change the values in first row based on the values in secod row,

Tags: perl, shell, unix, sed, awk

So I have this file that has over 480000 rows and 1380 columns.
I need to have a pipeline that adds F_ or M_ to the values in first row if the values in second row is Sex: Female or Sex: Male.

The first line in my file is basically individual ids followed by cell type -N or -G. The second line indicated whether that individual is a Female or Male the rest of the lines are probe_Ids in the first column and the other columns are their corresponding beta_value for each individual. If that would make more sense I'd add the few following lines.

My input file is like this (tab-separated) without the 1st column.

```
1740-N  1546-N  1546-G  1740-G  1228-G  5121-N  5121-G
Sex: Female Sex: Female Sex: Female Sex: Female Sex: Male   Sex: Female Sex: Female
```

My output should look like this (tab-separated) without the first column

```
F_1740-N    F_1546-N    F_1546-G    F_1740-G    M_1228-G    F_5121-N    F_5121-G
```

Note that the sex line is not outputted.

Could anyone help please? I would do it manually if I have small number of columns.

This could be done in any program; I'm not sticking with perl

Comment: Is this the first and second row of each file or paired rows throughout the file?

Comment: they're both in one file. Second row is the determinant for the first row but i don't need both I just need one as a header. and it's save me too much time.

Comment: I meant this is just the first and second rows in the file and not pairs of lines multiple places in the file but it sounds like it is.

Comment: Please show us rows 1,2,3, 4 and 5. Also, columns 4 and 5 so we can understand the question.

Comment: Those are tab-delimited columns I believe (edit the post and play with the leading spacing to see what I mean). And those should be rows one and two (which are all that should matter) assuming I understand everything correctly.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something here, but if you only need to edit a couple of lines in only one file, why do you need a script?

Comment: "480000 rows and 1380 columns"

Comment: Yes you're right Etan, at this point I'm only focusing on 1st and 2nd rows. the rest of the columns are kind of similar to the first few I posted but #s are different because they indicate different individuals. @EtanReisner

Comment: @pfnuesel - Yes, and?

Comment: @Kenosis because of the # of the columns. I actually edited few hundreds while everybody is asking these Qs.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the other 1380 columns look the same as the 3 that are posted here. I would also assume that the 480000 rows look similar to the one posted here, although that's not clear.

Comment: Just FYI @Kenosis is you have a huge file as this one it's impossible to open it and edit manually because you poor laptop will crash on you. Got it?

Comment: @user2997397 - OK. Got it now.  I think I was missing something here...

Comment: @user2997397 - Not all editors read the entire file into memory, so a laptop crash isn't inevitable--even in this case.  It does seem to be, however, a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'\t' '
NR%2 { split($0,a); next }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf "%s%s_%s", (i==1?"":FS), ($i~/Female/?"F":"M"), a[i]
    print ""
}
' file
F_1740-N        F_1546-N        F_1546-G        F_1740-G        M_1228-G       F_5121-N F_5121-G
```

Comment: Then you copy/pasted the script incorrectly or gave it an empty or corrupt input file as that's impossible otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a buffer of one line.

```
my $last_line = <>;
if ($last_line) {
   while (my $this_line = <>) {
      if ($this_line =~ /^Sex:/) {
         adjust_for_sex($last_line, $this_line);
         next;  # Don't display the Sex row.
      }

      print($last_line);
      $last_line = $this_line;
   }

   print($last_line);
}
```

And this is the code that does the actual change:

```
sub adjust_for_sex {
   my ($last_line, $this_line) = @_;

   chomp($last_line);
   my @last_fields = split /\t/, $last_line;

   chomp($this_line);
   my @this_fields = split /\t/, $this_line;

   for my $i (0..$#last_fields) {
      my ($sex) = $this_fields[$i] =~ /^Sex: (.)/
         or die;

      $last_fields[$i] = $sex . "_" . $last_fields[$i];
   }

   # Changes the first argument in the caller.
   $_[0] = join("\t", @last_fields) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: it didn't change the names actually or maybe I'm not doing it the right way

Comment: Got stuck in an infinite loop cause I used `redo` where I should have used `next`. Fixed. Anyway, based on new information --that there is only one sex line and that it's the second line of the file-- this solution is overkill.

Comment: It still gives me an output the same as the input.

Comment: @user2997397, No it doesn't. You changed something

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in awk. It is going to require a bit of memory though to store all the data from the first row though.

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"}

NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        f[i]=$i
    }
    next
}

NR == 2 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        $i=gensub(/Sex: ([FM]).*/, "\\1", "g", $i)
        $i=$i"_"f[i]
    }
    print
    next
}

{print}
```

If pairs of lines matching this pattern repeat throughout the file something like the following might do the job:

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"}

line && /^Sex: / {
    split(line, f)
    line=""

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        $i=substr($i, 0, 6)
        gsub(/^Sex: /, "", $i)
        printf "%s ", $i"_"f[i]
    }
    print ""
    next
}

line {print line}

{line=$0}
```

Comment: I got the impression that there might be id and sex lines later in the file. Is that the case, @user2997397?

Comment: I don't know. I tried asking but didn't get a good answer. If there are  and there aren't other lines in the file then just removing the NR patterns should work (and the default print too). If there are then something more like the perl answer below is necessary.

Comment: It would probably be worth mentioning **`awk`** since that seems to be the language in use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed. I meant to do that but managed to forget. Edited in now. Thanks.

Comment: and you should mention it's gawk-specific courtesy of gensub().

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing that out. I also noticed that I'd left out the value of FS that makes it work. Not my best answer effort apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This was written assuming the input file had repeating pairs of lines to be parsed together.  It could be easily modified to stop after parsing the first 2 lines, but I'm leaving it as-is, even though it doesn't answer the op's question after he/she clarified it.  Maybe it will be useful to someone else.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(IN, "in.txt") or die $!;
open(OUT, ">out.txt") or die $!;
my $secondLine ;
while(<IN>) {
  my $firstLine = $_;
  chomp $firstLine;
  $secondLine = <IN> || "";
  chomp $secondLine;
  # Break out if there are no more lines with data (actually, this just detects 1-2 blank lines in a row, not necessarily at the end of the file yet)
  if ((! $firstLine) && (! $secondLine)) { last }
  my @firstLine = split(/\s+/, $firstLine);
  my @secondLine = split(/\s*Sex:\s*/, $secondLine);
  # The first element in @secondLine will always be the "null" before the first "Sex: ".
  # Throw it away.
  shift @secondLine;
  if (scalar(@firstLine) != scalar(@secondLine)) { die "Uneven # of fields in these 2 lines:\n$firstLine\n$secondLine\n" }

  # OK, output time.
  for (my $i=0; $i<scalar(@firstLine); $i++) {
    print OUT substr($secondLine[$i], 0, 1) . "_$firstLine[$i] ";
  }
  print OUT "\n";
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);

if (! $secondLine) {
  warn "The file does not appear to have an even number of lines.\n";
}
```

Comment: I got the impression that the file had more than just id and sex lines. Is that the case, @user2997397? (If only the OP had followed up on the request to display more lines!)

Comment: @ikegami I don't really know what you mean with one id and sex line! It's one line of ids and one line of gender. Lines from 3 to 479973 are the actual data

Comment: So no, there's just one

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


while(<>) {
   chop;
   @N=split;
   $_=<>;
   chop;
   s/\s*Sex:\s*//g;s/emale/ /g;s/ale/ /g;
   @S=split;
   foreach $k (0..$#N) {
     $i=$N[$k]; $g=$S[$k];
     print "$g" . '_' . "$i  " ;
   }
   print "\n";
}
```

Comment: I got the impression that the file had more than just id and sex lines. Is that the case, @user2997397? (If only the OP had followed up on the request to display more lines!)

Comment: not working too, and could you please explain to me what are @N, @S, $k, $N,$i, and $g, I got errors regarding these symbols

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri '1{N;:a;s/(\b[0-9]{4}-[GN].*\n)\s*Sex:\s*(.)\S+/\2_\1/;ta;s/\n//}' file
```

This combines line 1 and 2 and then does a substitution loop until no further columns can be matched.

Comment: Didn't work with me, kept getting errors such as (sed: illegal option -- r)